# Default.aspx I have a home button its a text box so if i click that it has to go to another page

Tags: c#-4.0

If we  click a text box it has to go to another page. Help out with this code in c# creating a website in .net c#
Trying to create an example program on my personal laptop. So help me with this

Comment: What did u tried so far? Provide your code / error then we can guide you.

Comment: Home button can't be a TextBox. Plz refer some basic tutorials.

Comment: Cant understand the question at all

Comment: when we click a button it  goes  to another aspx page

Comment: myself new to this c#  trying in different ways thanks kayathiri